# Logarithmic scale

Tags: math, audio, scale, frequency, logarithm

I am programming a small synthesizer application and I input musical notes by clicking along the length of a bar. Now, the musical scale is logarithmic and my question is, how do I convert the position of the mouse to a relevant pitch. At the moment I calculate a ratio. It works, sort of, but I get a wide range of closely packed low notes, and at the far end I takes of with just a few pixels translating into multiple octaves.
Basically I want, if I click at the center of the bar (1/2), the frequency is doubled, and 1/4 is another double in freq. etc…
I'm being stupid here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frequencies of musical notes are indeed logarithmic. The frequency doubles when you go one octave higher, and halves when you go one octave lower. A standard A is exactly 440Hz.

So, you need a power law to translate location into a frequency. Something like f*2.0^(x/w) where w is the width of an octave, f is a scale factor and ^ is the power operator.

Comment: In addition, there are many other tunings commonly used.  For pianos, see stretch tuning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretched_tuning).  See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_tuning#Temperament_and_beating

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the implementation. I'm programming in c#, but a general pseudo syntax is fine... :) Thanks for the response!

Comment: Isn't the width of an octave always a factor of 2? What would x be in the above?

Comment: I guess i could implement it programmatically. But what would f, x and w be?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to create a kind of on-screen keyboard. x is the position of the mouse pointer. w is the width of an octave, so about 1/8th of your total window size for a piano keyboard, and f is a scale factor such that you get the right pitch. If xMiddleC is the x-value corresponding to a middle C, you can compute the frequency as: `261 * Math.Pow(2, (double)(x - xMiddleC) / w)`

Comment: Not only are you probably correct in your computations, you also understood me perfectly! I'll mark it solved now as it is up to me to get it to work! Big Thanks!